# Using Apache Drill to query kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-drill

I have been trying to figure out a way to use Apache Drill to query Kafka topics using SQL. Can some one give me a starter point so as to how can I connect drill to kafka. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Till Drill 1.4, there is no support to query over Kafka topics using Drill.

Comment: See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-4779

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for querying Kafka has been added in Drill 1.12 . I haven't used it myself but I will provide a quick outline of the general configuration required. If you run into more issues please contact us on Drill's mailing list http://drill.apache.org/mailinglists/ . We can help you debug the issue and then post the results here.

The general outline of what you need to do is the following:

1. Create a storage plugin in Drill's web ui. Name the plugin **kafka**

   ```
   {
     "bootstrap.servers": "broker_1:port1,broker_2:port2",
     "group.id": "drill-consumer-group-1",
     "enabled": true
   }
   ```
2. After creating the plugin configuration, set the appropriate kafka message deserializer for your query:
   `alter session set store.kafka.record.reader = org.apache.drill.exec.store.kafka.decoders.JsonMessageReader`
3. Also set a poll timeout that works for your query:
   `alter session set store.kafka.poll.timeout = 200`
4. Try out a query: `select * from kafka.myTopic;`

Comment: I've try your suggestion but got errors. With `alter session set store.kafka.record.reader = 'org.apache.drill.exec.store.kafka.decoders.JsonMessageReader'` I got "DATA_READ ERROR: Failed to read JSON record", with `alter session set store.kafka.record.reader = 'org.apache.drill.exec.store.kafka.decoders.AvroMessageReader'` - "VALIDATION ERROR: Failed to initialize message reader : org.apache.drill.exec.store.kafka.decoders.AvroMessageReader"